# TCSH scripts and the scp command

Tags: scp, csh, tcsh

I'm scratching my head at the following odd behaviour seen under Ubuntu Linaro (on a Parallella).  This scp command works fine by itself:

```
$ scp user@UNIT1:~/myMPI/filename user@UNIT2:~/myMPI/
```

But once I wrap it into a script:

```
#!/bin/tcsh -f

scp user@UNIT1:~/myMPI/$1 user@UNIT2:~/myMPI/
```

and issue it, I get this:

```
$ thescript filename

user: invalid user name
```

There are no spaces or periods in the user name, and that would fail on the command line as well, not just in the script. Nevertheless, tcsh is somehow mangling the scp command.

Help?

Comment: Your script starts with `#!/bin/sh -f`, so it's a Bourne shell script, not a tcsh script. tcsh scripts need `#!/bin/tcsh -f`, where `-f` tells the shell not to load startup files.  The `-f` option for `/bin/sh` is completely different (it disables pathname expansion), and you don't need it here.

Comment: A copy-paste error on my part, now fixed. Unfortunately, the problem remains entire.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Is that the *exact* content of your tcsh script, or did you modify it for posting? (Is the user name really `user`, and the host names `UNIT1` and `UNIT2`?)

Comment: The host names are verbatim, the actual user name on each host is 'linaro'.

Comment: I suggest updating your question by copy-and-pasting the *entire* script verbatim. Also, try the same script (or one as similar as possible) on a non-Linaro system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kenster nailed it: there were parasitic $C2 (Â) $AD (soft hyphen) character pairs hiding in front of the user name in the script file. I'm not sure how they got in there (nor why Leafpad didn't show them), but now that they're gone, the script works as expected.

Thanks also to Keith Thompson for trying.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code within the `scp` program which emits that error:

```
int
okname(char *cp0)
{
    int c;
    char *cp;

    cp = cp0;
    do {
        c = (int)*cp;
        if (c & 0200)
            goto bad;
        if (!isalpha(c) && !isdigit((unsigned char)c)) {
            switch (c) {
            case '\'':
            case '"':
            case '`':
            case ' ':
            case '#':
                goto bad;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    } while (*++cp);
    return (1);

bad:    fprintf(stderr, "%s: invalid user name\n", cp0);
    return (0);
}
```

It doesn't accept usernames containing characters with ordinal values above 127, or certain punctuation characters. Presumably one of the redacted usernames in your script violates one of these conditions. Offhand, the first thing I'd suspect is that you have an accented character in there, or maybe some unicode text.

Comment: Nope. The user name is 'linaro'.  And, again, the error would show up on the command line if this were the case. No, this is some weirder interaction between tcsh and scp.

Comment: You could try running the script file through "od -a" to see if there are any funny characters in there.